# how to  set title

Tags: iphone

```
NSString *formatString = NSLocalizedString(@"%1$i of %2$i", @"Picture X out of Y total.");
NSString *countTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:formatString, currentIndex_ + 1, photoCount_,  nil];
[self setTitle:countTitle];
```

in this code the title  showing Ex." 22 of 44" that means 22nd photos out of 44
i want add title like  "album name + countTitle" which is above in the code so that wil  become like  and i want to give the name of album is "Flickr"

Ex.  "Flickr 22 of 44"   how the code will be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is pretty simple, you just need to add an extra format string modifier and add the variable in the correct place in your `stringWithFormat:` like so (where `albumName` is the name of your album`):

```
NSString *formatString = NSLocalizedString(@"%@ %1$i of %2$i", @"Picture X out of Y total.");
NSString *countTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:formatString, albumName, currentIndex_ + 1, photoCount_,  nil];
[self setTitle:countTitle];
```

Also just to note, instead of using `%1$i` and `%1$i` for integers, you can just use `%d` for C Integers in your format string like so:

```
NSString *formatString = NSLocalizedString(@"%@ %d of %d", @"Picture X out of Y total.");
NSString *countTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:formatString, albumName, currentIndex_ + 1, photoCount_,  nil];
[self setTitle:countTitle];
```